# Create a menu app that displays meal price totals, incremeneting radio button values in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, radio-button, jframe

I have an assignment to create a restaurant menu app that allows a user to choose a drink, appetizer, entree, and dessert with three options for each. I have to use radio buttons. I am supposed to increment the mealTotals for each person (every time the nextPerson button gets pressed, mealTotal is added on to the next person's total) to print a total for the entire table. Any help in how I can have mealTotal increment properly for each person and then get a tableTotal would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MenuApp extends JFrame {

//    static JFrame frame;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame aFrame = new MenuApp();
    aFrame.setVisible(true);

}

public MenuApp() {

    setTitle("Leah Thompson's Restaurant App");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Buttons buttonPanel = new Buttons();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    setContentPane(buttonPanel);
    pack();


}
}
```

And the Buttons class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Buttons extends JPanel {

private final JTextField nameField;

String[] drinkChoice = {"Coke", "Beer", "Wine"};
String[] appChoice = {"Soup", "Salad", "Brie"};
String[] entreeChoice = {"Pasta", "Steak", "Burger"};
String[] dessertChoice = {"Tiramisu", "Cheesecake", "Chocolate Cake"};

JRadioButton[] drinkButtons = new JRadioButton[drinkChoice.length];
JRadioButton[] appButtons = new JRadioButton[appChoice.length];
JRadioButton[] entreeButtons = new JRadioButton[entreeChoice.length];
JRadioButton[] dessertButtons = new JRadioButton[dessertChoice.length];

ButtonGroup buttonGroupDrink = new ButtonGroup();
ButtonGroup buttonGroupApp = new ButtonGroup();
ButtonGroup buttonGroupEntree = new ButtonGroup();
ButtonGroup buttonGroupDessert = new ButtonGroup();

JButton mealCost;
JButton nextPerson;
JButton submitOrder;

ArrayList<Double> tableTotal = new ArrayList(0);

double mealTotal = 0;
double mealTotal1 = 0;

public Buttons(){

    ActionListener nameEntered = new NameEntered(); 
    add(new JLabel("Name (hit enter after typing name)"));
    nameField = new JTextField(10);
    add(nameField);
    nameField.addActionListener(nameEntered);

    ActionListener drinkSelection = new DrinkSelectionChangeMade();
    ActionListener appSelection = new AppSelectionChangeMade();
    ActionListener entreeSelection = new EntreeSelectionChangeMade();
    ActionListener dessertSelection = new DessertSelectionChangeMade();

    add(new JLabel("Choose a Drink"));
    for (int i = 0; i < drinkChoice.length; i++) {
        drinkButtons[i] = new JRadioButton(drinkChoice[i]);
        drinkButtons[i].getModel().setActionCommand(drinkChoice[i]);
        drinkButtons[i].addActionListener(drinkSelection);
        buttonGroupDrink.add(drinkButtons[i]);
        add(drinkButtons[i]);
//            if (i == 0) {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 2;
//            } else if (i == 1) {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 3;
//            } else {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 5;
//            }

    }

    add(new JLabel("Choose an Appetizer"));
    for (int i = 0; i < appChoice.length; i++) {
        appButtons[i] = new JRadioButton(appChoice[i]);
        appButtons[i].getModel().setActionCommand(appChoice[i]);
        appButtons[i].addActionListener(appSelection);
        buttonGroupApp.add(appButtons[i]);
        add(appButtons[i]);
//            if (i == 0) {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 6;
//            } else if (i == 1) {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 7;
//            } else {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 8;
//            }

    }

    add(new JLabel("Choose an Entree"));
    for (int i = 0; i < entreeChoice.length; i++) {
        entreeButtons[i] = new JRadioButton(entreeChoice[i]);
        entreeButtons[i].getModel().setActionCommand(entreeChoice[i]);
        entreeButtons[i].addActionListener(entreeSelection);
        buttonGroupEntree.add(entreeButtons[i]);
        add(entreeButtons[i]);
//            if (i == 0) {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 12;
//            } else if (i == 1) {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 20;
//            } else {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 10;
//            }

    }

    add(new JLabel("Choose a Dessert"));
    for (int i = 0; i < dessertChoice.length; i++) {
        dessertButtons[i] = new JRadioButton(dessertChoice[i]);
        dessertButtons[i].getModel().setActionCommand(dessertChoice[i]);
        dessertButtons[i].addActionListener(dessertSelection);
        buttonGroupDessert.add(dessertButtons[i]);
        add(dessertButtons[i]);
//            if (i == 0) {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 7;
//            } else if (i == 1) {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 6;
//            } else {
//                mealTotal = mealTotal + 5;
//            }

    }


    mealCost = new JButton("Total Cost of Meal");
    add(mealCost);
    ActionListener mealPrice = new MealCostPressed();
    mealCost.addActionListener(mealPrice);

    nextPerson = new JButton("Next Person");
    add(nextPerson);
    ActionListener next = new NextPersonPressed();
    nextPerson.addActionListener(next);

    submitOrder = new JButton("Submit Order");
    add(submitOrder);
    ActionListener submit = new SubmitPressed();
    submitOrder.addActionListener(submit);

    //tableTotal.add(mealTotal);
    //add(new JLabel("Your total is: " + mealTotal));

}

private class NameEntered implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String name = nameField.getText();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

 private class DrinkSelectionChangeMade implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String drink = buttonGroupDrink.getSelection().getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(drink + " as a drink");
        if(drink == "Coke"){
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 1.95;
        }
        else if(drink == "Beer"){
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 2.95;
        }
        else{
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 4.95;
        }
    }
}

    private class AppSelectionChangeMade implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String app = buttonGroupApp.getSelection().getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(app + " as an appetizer");
        if(app == "Soup"){
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 3.95;
        }
        else if(app == "Salad"){
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 4.95;
        }
        else{
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 7.95;
        }
    }
}

private class EntreeSelectionChangeMade implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String entree = buttonGroupEntree.getSelection().getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(entree + " as an entree");
        if(entree == "Pasta"){
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 11.95;
        }
        else if(entree == "Steak"){
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 19.95;
        }
        else{
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 9.95;
        }
    }
}

private class DessertSelectionChangeMade implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String dessert = buttonGroupDessert.getSelection().getActionCommand();
            System.out.println(dessert + " as a dessert");
            if(dessert == "Tiramisu"){
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 6.95;
        }
        else if(dessert == "Cheesecake"){
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 5.95;
        }
        else{
            mealTotal = mealTotal + 4.95;
        }
            tableTotal.add(mealTotal);
    }
}
private class NextPersonPressed implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      //removeAll();
      JFrame nextFrame = new MenuApp();
      nextFrame.setVisible(true);
      System.out.println("Next Customer: "); 
    }
}

private class MealCostPressed implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mealCost, mealTotal);
    }
}

private class SubmitPressed implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(nextPerson, "Thank you for your order. Please Exit Now.");
        System.out.println("The total cost for the table is: " + tableTotal);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need several things...

- Some component to display tally, declared as an instance variable
- A `tally` variable to maintain the tally (declared as a `double`), yes you can use `long`, but I'm trying not to confuse you.
- Some way to determine the value of the item that was selected/unselected.

When one of the `ActionListener`s is called, you need to deteremine the value of the item that was selected, you then need to determine if the source is selected or not.

If the item was selected, you need to add it's value to the `tally`, if it's unselected, you need to subtract the value.

You then need to set the value of the tally component, probably using something like `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance`

Comment: I changed my code so that it gets the mealTotal for one person, would you have any suggestions on how to have the mealTotal add for each new person that is entered(i.e., each time the NextPerson button is pressed, the mealTotal from the previous person gets added to the new person's mealTotal for a double tableTotal that prints at the end? Thanks!

Comment: That depends, do you want to keep each item from the previous person or just the tally. If you want to maintain what each person ordered, create a POJO as a container for the values and add them to a List

Comment: I just added an arrayList, tableTotal, and have tried adding mealTotal to it, but it only ever adds the last person's mealTotal, so there is only ever one value in it. I cannot get it to add each person's meal total and store them all in tableTotal...

Comment: Sounds like you have a reference problem, but it's difficult to know without some code. Maybe you should consider raising another question

Comment: Thank you, I just added a new question with the updated code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688332/cannot-properly-add-values-to-arraylist-from-radio-buttons-java-gui